# How can I fix my Wagtail URL namespace and explorer when adding wagtail to a current project?

Tags: django, python-3.x, wagtail, cookiecutter

My issue is my URL is coming up mysite.com/test-news-1/ instead of mysite.com/news/test-news-1/

I've started a new project using cookiecutter-django. I then wanted to add wagtail cms to the project and followed the docs to do so.

I get the wagtail admin page up fine, at /cms/ instead of /admin/ like it says to do on this page - http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.3.1/getting_started/integrating_into_django.html

I added a few apps just to practice and get used to wagtail, one directly copied from the wagtail blog example. This is where my issue starts.

The wagtail admin Explorer does not list my apps like it shows on the wagtail site https://wagtail.io/features/explorer/, instead it just says "Welcome to your new Wagtail site!" When I select Add Child Page it allows me to select the app pages I have set up and seems to go by my models just fine. But when I post something and click go to live site it comes up as mysite.com/blog1/ instead of mysite.com/blog/blog1/

I believe my problem that I dont understand the final part of the doc page that I linked above. It says,

> Note that there’s one small difference when not using the Wagtail
>   project template: Wagtail creates an initial homepage of the basic
>   type Page, which does not include any content fields beyond the title.
>   You’ll probably want to replace this with your own HomePage class -
>   when you do so, ensure that you set up a site record (under Settings /
>   Sites in the Wagtail admin) to point to the new homepage.

I tried adding the homepage model from the doc page, but this didn't seem to help at all.

I'm very inexperienced, this is my urls.py file, if you need to see other files please let me know.

```
urls.py    

from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.views import defaults as default_views

from wagtail.wagtailadmin import urls as wagtailadmin_urls
from wagtail.wagtaildocs import urls as wagtaildocs_urls
from wagtail.wagtailcore import urls as wagtail_urls

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='pages/home.html'), name="home"),
    url(r'^about/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='pages/about.html'), name="about"),

    # Django Admin, use {% url 'admin:index' %}
    url(settings.ADMIN_URL, include(admin.site.urls)),

    # User management
    url(r'^users/', include("contestchampion.users.urls", namespace="users")),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),

    # Your stuff: custom urls includes go here

    # Wagtail cms
    url(r'^cms/', include(wagtailadmin_urls)),
    url(r'^documents/', include(wagtaildocs_urls)),
    url(r'', include(wagtail_urls)),

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

if settings.DEBUG:
    # This allows the error pages to be debugged during development, just visit
    # these url in browser to see how these error pages look like.
    urlpatterns += [
        url(r'^400/$', default_views.bad_request, kwargs={'exception': Exception("Bad Request!")}),
        url(r'^403/$', default_views.permission_denied, kwargs={'exception': Exception("Permission Denied")}),
        url(r'^404/$', default_views.page_not_found, kwargs={'exception': Exception("Page not Found")}),
        url(r'^500/$', default_views.server_error),
    ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two url confs are in conflict =

```
url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='pages/home.html'), name="home"),
url(r'', include(wagtail_urls)),
```

One must change, otherwise Django will always resolve the base url of `yourdomain.com/' to the first entry. One easy way to fix this is to update the second-

```
url(r'^content/', include(wagtail_urls)),
```

Now your Wagtail root page will be accessible at `yourdomain.com/content`.

As for `mysite.com/blog/blog1/` not coming up, that Url would assume that, from your Wagtail root page, there's a page w/ slug 'blog', and then a child page of that with slug `blog1`. The tree structure of your Wagtail site determines the URLs by default. If you want to override that you'll have to use the RoutablePageMixin as described [here](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.0b1/contrib/routablepage.html).

Comment: Now I see. I was under the impression that wagtail automatically made a /blog/ for my child blog pages, but this is not the case(which is good). After reading your answer I went back and looked closer at the pictures of the docs and now its clear.